# LinkedIn API - Unable to retrieve the list of companies/organizations made by user

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm using the LinkedIn API to create posts on LINKEDIN.
The user is authenticated and fetched fine and whatever I create or post is showing in the profile as well.
The issue comes out that I am unable to fetch out the list of company/organization pages which a specific user might or might not have.
I'm not able to find any flag related to it in the DOCS as well.
I hope sure any of you can help.

```
$company = $linkedinAccount->get('https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies?is-company-admin=true');
```

Nothing coming ou from it.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect_uri param doesnt match the one you setup, its missing the "https://" part

You can use any url you setup on app page on "redirect_url" but it needs to be exactly the same including the https:// part

Try this:
https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?state=f4e31810ec846a4c82be0799e64c0442&scope=r_emailaddress%20r_liteprofile%20w_member_social&response_type=code&approval_prompt=auto&client_id=81cniud0fnh6vv&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fbleupage.iserver.purelogics.net%2Findex.php%2Flinkedin

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn v1 API is no longer working.

I would suggest using v2 and to see which agencies the authenticated member has access you can use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-access-control) section of the API, your application will need permission to request `rw_organization_admin` permission to the user though so you might want to check that on the Auth tab in https://developers.linkedin.com